# HighChart Avoiding points on the plotbackground

Tags: typescript, highcharts

I have spline of percentage 0-100 and need the point not to be on the border (when y=0 or y=100) (expectation: 7px padding between background border to points)

[image: screenshot]

for padding of left & right I used

```
yAxis: [{
    minPadding: 0.07,
    maxPadding: 0.07,
  ...
```

but it didn't work the same for xAxis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to disable the `softThreshold` property:

> **softThreshold: boolean**
>
> When this is true, the series will not cause the Y axis to cross the zero plane (or threshold option) unless the data actually crosses the plane.
>   (...)

```
series: [{
    softThreshold: false,
    ...
}]
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ep0zd9gm/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.spline.softThreshold